# Взаимосоответствие между элементами списков

Tags: python

Добрый день
решаю следующую задачу:
27. Создать список из целочисленных элементов, количество которых не превышает 25. Необходимо:
    ввести индексы чисел i и j такие, что удовлетворяют условию: (1 < i < j < 25);
    числа, находящиеся между индексами, включая сами индексы, заменить на символы латинского алфавита, находящиеся на тех же позициях;
    упорядочить вставку по алфавиту.

Я хочу создать вместе с списком на 25 чисел, список из 25 букв латинского алфавита, но не знаю как заменить срез из списков чисел на срез из списка букв. Гуглил, не помогло. Прошу помощи у мастеров.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для замены списка чисел на список букв по индексу можно воспользоваться строкой `ascii_lowercase` - по сути, это алфавит. Допустим, у нас есть список `a`, в котором есть натуральные числа (максимальное не больше, чем количество букв в алфавите), для сопоставления буквам по индексу можно сделать так

```
from string import ascii_lowercase

a = list(range(1, 26))
b = [ascii_lowercase[i - 1] for i in a]
```

Получим:

> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25]
>
> ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y']